# Discrepancy in Disk Usage Data Between EC2 Server and AWS Console: Seeking Guidance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am experiencing an issue with disk usage data display in the AWS console. I joined the service approximately a month ago and have been actively using the free tier of the EC2 service with Ubuntu installed. Throughout this period, I have been closely monitoring metrics and resource usage statistics.

However, recently I noticed a discrepancy in the displayed data. When I run the command df -Th on my EC2 server, it shows that only 5.1 gigabytes of disk space is being used. Meanwhile, in the AWS console, disk usage data is nearly three times higher, amounting to 12 gigabytes.

On my server, I have only installed Python versions 3.10 and 3.11, along with a local MongoDB Server Community database. I am certain that I have not used 12 gigabytes of disk space.

I would like to know if anyone else has encountered a similar issue and, if so, how it can be resolved. Unfortunately, I cannot reach out to AWS technical support as their services are only available to paying customers.

I would appreciate any help and advice regarding this situation. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You pay for the size of the EBS volumes, not the used space on them, so the results of `df` will have nothing to do with your charges.  It looks like you've had a 30gb volume up since something like the 15th, meaning you've used around 15 GB/Mo.

Comment: @AnonCoward I find your response quite intriguing and insightful because I checked the creation date of the EBS, and it shows 12.14.2023. However, I still don't grasp what the outcome will be for me once this limit is reached, and I'm still uncertain whether this limit is related to my storage.

Comment: The outcome is once you use up the resources in the free tier, you pay for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an Amazon EBS volume is created, a size is specified. This is the size of the virtual disk and **you are charged for that complete size**.

The operating system running on the EC2 instance is responsible for managing how data is **stored** on a block storage device (Amazon EBS volume). AWS cannot 'see into' the instance so it has **no knowledge of how much of the disk is 'used'**.

Therefore, AWS will say that the disk is the complete (maximum) size of the disk, while the operating system will show how much of that space is 'used'. **They will not match**, since they are reporting different information.

Also, please note that **EBS volumes are charged "per GB-month"**. So, a 10 GB disk for a full month would be 10 GB-months. A 20 GB disk for *half* a month would also be 10 GB-months.

Comment: Okay, but I have one more question. Let's assume I started using the volume at the beginning of December 1st at midnight, and this month has 31 days, while my EBS is billed at 30 gigabytes per month. Will I have to pay for an additional day as if it were one used gigabyte? This is intriguing because on the AWS page, it is mentioned that 1 gigabyte will be valid for 730 hours, not 750 hours per month. [image](https://imgur.com/a/DD7XuKC)